# Plot $\arg(z)$ in an Argand diagram and display the angle

Tags: graphics, complex

I'd like to ask you about the way to show the $\arg(z)$ annotation about the angle. My point is to show $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ on the image.

What I mean:

[image: Argand diagram]
<sub>(source: [brocku.ca](http://www.physics.brocku.ca/PPLATO/h-flap/math3_3f_2.png))</sub>

Is there any way to achieve similar effect in Mathematica?

My code:

```
    Show[%6, Axes -> True, Method -> {"ScRegionPlot[
      Pi/4. <= Arg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -.1, 1}, 
      GridLines -> {{-.15}, {0}}, 
      PlotPoints -> 60, Show[%6,Axes\[Rule]True,Method\[Rule]{" \
ScRegionPlot[
       Norm[x + I y + .15] < 0.6 && 
       Pi/4. <= Arg[x + I y] <= Pi, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -.1, 1}, 
       AspectRatio -> 
       Automatic] alingFunctions "\[Rule]None," \
TransparentPolygonMesh "\[Rule]True}]
      AspectRatio -> Automatic]alingFunctions" -> None, 
   "TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {2 π/3, 5 π/6}], Axes -> True]`?

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to print the angle on the image. Both of them. Another example: http://www.physics.brocku.ca/PPLATO/h-flap/math3_3f_2.png

Comment: Try adding `Text[#, {Cos[#], Sin[#]}, {1, -1}] & /@ {2 π/3, 5 π/6}`

Comment: @terry_8 Maybe you want to try [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
roots = z /. Solve[z^3 == 1, z];
pts = {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ roots;
args = Arg /@ Cases[roots, _?(Im[N[#]] != 0 &)];

Module[{pr = 1.25, radius = {1/4, 3/8}},
 Graphics[{
   Thick,
   Arrow[{{-pr, 0}, {pr, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, -pr}, {0, pr}}],
   Text[Style[Subscript[z, 0], 18, Bold],
    pts[[1]], {0, -2}],
   Text[Style[Subscript[z, 1], 18, Bold],
    pts[[3]], {0, -2}],
   Text[Style[Subscript[z, 2], 18, Bold],
    pts[[2]], {0, 2}],
   {
      Circle[{0, 0}, #[[1]], {0, #[[2]]}],
      Text[Style[#[[2]], 14, Bold], #[[1]]*
        Through[{Cos, Sin}[#[[2]]/2]],
       {-1.25, -Sign[#[[2]]]}]} & /@
    Transpose[{radius, args}],
   AbsolutePointSize[10],
   Point[pts],
   AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}],
   Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ pts},
  Axes -> True,
  Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 1/2], Range[-1, 1, 1]},
  TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14],
  PlotRange -> {{-pr, pr}, {-pr, pr}},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im})]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A question on plotting complex numbers begs for an answer that directly uses complex numbers rather than requires pulling the complex numbers apart into real and imaginary parts. Such an answer is allowed by David Park's *Presentations(* add-on (https://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html):

```
   <<Presentations`

   roots = z /. Solve[z^3 == 1, z];
   args = Arg /@ Select[roots, ! Element[#, Reals] &];

   With[{rng = 1.25, radii = {1/4, 3/8}, arcOffset = 1.4},
     Draw2D[{
       Thick,
       (*arrow axes *)
       ComplexArrow[{-rng, rng}], ComplexArrow[{-rng I, rng I}],

       (* labeled arcs *)
       ComplexCircle[0, First@#, {0, Last@#}] & /@ 
       Transpose[{radii, args}],
       ComplexText[Last@#, 
       ComplexPolar[ arcOffset First@#, Last@#/2], {-1, 0}] & /@ 
       Transpose[{radii, args}],

       (* lines to roots *)
       Dashing[0.035], 
       ComplexLine[{0, #}] & /@ Rest@roots,

      (* labeled roots *)
      PointSize[0.025], ComplexPoint /@ roots,
      ComplexText[Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
        Transpose[{Style[#, 18] & /@ {Subscript[z, 0], Subscript[z, 2],Subscript[z, 1]}, 
          roots, {{0, -2}, {0, 2}, {0, -2}}}]
     },
     PlotRange -> rng,
     Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Re, Im},
     Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 1/2], Range[-1, 1, 1]},
     TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14, FontWeight -> "Medium"],
     BaseStyle -> Directive[14, Bold]
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

Here's the same thing decorated a bit with use of color, etc.:

```
   With[{rng = 1.25, radii = {1/4, 3/8}, arcOffset = 1.4},
     Draw2D[{
       Thick,
       (*arrow axes *)
       {Gray, ComplexArrow[{-rng, rng}], ComplexArrow[{-rng I, rng I}]},

       (* labeled arcs *)
       {Legacy@SeaGreen, ComplexCircle[0, First@#, {0, Last@#}] & /@ 
         Transpose[{radii, args}]},
       ComplexText[Last@#, 
       ComplexPolar[ arcOffset First@#, Last@#/2], {-1, 0}] & /@ 
       Transpose[{radii, args}],

       (* lines to roots *)
       {Dashing[0.035], Legacy@BrownOchre,
       ComplexLine[{0, #}] & /@ Rest@roots},

      (* labeled roots *)
      ComplexCirclePoint[#, 5, Black, Legacy@CadmiumOrange] & /@ roots,
      ComplexText[Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
        Transpose[{Style[#, 18] & /@ {Subscript[z, 0], Subscript[z, 2],Subscript[z, 1]}, 
          roots, {{0, -2}, {0, 2}, {0, -2}}}]
     },
     PlotRange -> rng,
     Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {Re, Im},
     Ticks -> {Range[-1, 1, 1/2], Range[-1, 1, 1]},
     TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14, FontWeight -> "Medium"],
     BaseStyle -> Directive[14, Bold],
     Background -> Lighter@Legacy@Linen,
     PlotLabel -> "The cube roots of unity"
   ]
  ]
```

[image]