# How do I plot complex numbers as Argand diagram

Tags: plotting

Given three complex numbers:

$a=3+2i=(3,2) $ in $(Re,Im)$ plane.

$b=-1-3i=(-1,-3)$ in $(Re,Im)$ plane.

$c=a+b=2-i=(2,-1)$ in $(Re,Im)$ plane.

Now, I want to plot these three complex numbers like this
[image]
Every complex number needs to be plotted like an arrow from $(0,0)$ to its respective coordinates.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible earlier duplicate: [(15637)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15637), but no arrow, if arrows pose a significantly distinctive problem. Also related: [(97245)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97245)

Comment: Also related: [(131125)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/plotting-complex-solutions-in-argand-plane-as-arrows).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{a, b, c} = {3 + 2 I, -1 - 3 I, 2 - I};
reim = ReIm @ {a, b, c};
data = {{0, 0}, #} & /@ reim;
labels = {"a", "b", "c"};
Show[ListLinePlot[data, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[.05],  AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 1], 
  ListPlot[Callout[#, #2] & @@@ Transpose@{reim, labels}, PlotStyle -> None]] /. 
  Line -> Arrow
```

[image]